# Screen blinks when user goes to another activity and comes back to MainActivity.class

Tags: android, android-studio, google-drive-api

My user is logged in but when I call below lines of code, if a user is logged in I am getting need permission error.

```
  mDriveServiceHelper = new DriveServiceHelper(getGoogleDriveService(getApplicationContext(), alreadyloggedAccount, "appname"));


 public static Drive getGoogleDriveService(Context context, GoogleSignInAccount account, String appName) {
        GoogleAccountCredential credential =
                GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
                        context, Collections.singleton(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE));
        credential.setSelectedAccount(account.getAccount());
        com.google.api.services.drive.Drive googleDriveService =
                new com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.Builder(
                        AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                        new GsonFactory(),
                        credential)
                        .setApplicationName(appName)
                        .build();
        return googleDriveService;
    }
```

In my case every time I have to call the below methods then only it works.

when I call ***requestSignIn()*** and then ***`startActivityForResult(googleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(), REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN)`***. then only if user is not having permission the drive access popup is coming and next time when user logins to the app that drive access popup is not coming (which is expected). but the application is trying to open something (some activity or google drive popup) I think and as the user is having permission, it is not showing popup but the screen blinks once every time we go to another activity and come back on mainactivity.class. (this google drive code is written in main activity)

```
 private void requestSignIn() {

        Log.d(TAG, "Requesting sign-in");
        GoogleSignInOptions signInOptions =
                new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                        .requestScopes(new Scope(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE))
                        .requestEmail()
                        .build();

        googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, signInOptions);


    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent resultData) {

        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN:
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && resultData != null) {
                    handleSignInResult(resultData);
                }
                break;


        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, resultData);
    }

    String TAG = ":::: Backup User Data ::::::::::";
    private void handleSignInResult(Intent result) {
        GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(result)
                .addOnSuccessListener(googleAccount -> {
                    //System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>> handleSignInResult inside Mainactivity>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>. ");
                    Log.d(TAG, "Signed in as " + googleAccount.getEmail());

                    // Use the authenticated account to sign in to the Drive service.
                    GoogleAccountCredential credential =
                            GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
                                    this, Collections.singleton(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE));
                    credential.setSelectedAccount(googleAccount.getAccount());
                    Drive googleDriveService =
                            new Drive.Builder(
                                    AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                                    new GsonFactory(),
                                    credential)
                                    .setApplicationName("Drive API Migration")
                                    .build();

                    // The DriveServiceHelper encapsulates all REST API and SAF functionality.
                    // Its instantiation is required before handling any onClick actions.
                    mDriveServiceHelper = new DriveServiceHelper(googleDriveService);
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(exception -> Log.e(TAG, "Unable to sign in.", exception));
    }
```

i dont want that black line should pass from my screen everytime i go to another screen and comes back to MainActivity.class. (i think the black is passing from screen because whenever i am coming to MainActivity.class my code is again checking for google drive access and trying to show popup but as user is having permission the popup is disappearing)

can you please help me in above issue.

Comment: Hi! I got the same question with you. Did you find any solution to avoid the blink?

Comment: not found any solution :(

Comment: Taking a lot of hours to study, I find an answer. Please refer to my post answer!

Answer (score 1):

Studying into the source code of related classes, I find this function GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount should be useful. ***Call requestSignIn() at first time. If it's signed in before, use below function instead of requestSignIn().*** This avoids startActivityForResult() and the blink.

```
private void handleSignInWithoutActivity() { //a little modification from handleSignInResult()
    GoogleSignInAccount googleAccount = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(getApplicationContext());

    if(googleAccount!=null){
                Log.d(TAG, "Signed in as " + googleAccount.getEmail());

                // Use the authenticated account to sign in to the Drive service.
                GoogleAccountCredential credential =
                        GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
                                this, Collections.singleton(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE));
                credential.setSelectedAccount(googleAccount.getAccount());
                Drive googleDriveService =
                        new Drive.Builder(
                                AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                                new GsonFactory(),
                                credential)
                                .setApplicationName(getString(R.string.app_name))
                                .build();

                // The DriveServiceHelper encapsulates all REST API and SAF functionality.
                // Its instantiation is required before handling any onClick actions.
                mDriveServiceHelper = new DriveServiceHelper(googleDriveService);
    }else {
        //impossibly because it's signed in before. Error handle if it happens.
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Fisher, i have tried this but the problem is my user is logged in but google drive access popup is not coming so when i am doing backup in MainActivity.class i am getting need permission error.

Comment: I've studied your codes. It looks you just use handleSignInWithoutActivity() to replace requestSignIn(). requestSignIn() is never called. Please notice it needs first time to call requestSignIn(). Then use handleSignInWithoutActivity() to avoid startActivityForResult() and the blink.

Comment: i have implemented google account signin option in LoginActivity.java and after google signin user is sent to MainActivity.java where i am getting alreadysigninacccount thats why i am only calling handleSignInWithoutActivity(). can you please let me know whether i have to do change in LoginActivity.java or MainActivity.java

Comment: i tried implementing call requestSignIn() in LoginActivity.java but ***mDriveServiceHelper = new DriveServiceHelper(googleDriveService);*** is required in MainActivity.java which i am creating in LoginActivity.java in updated code. i dont know how to send mDriveServiceHelper object to MainActivity.java

Comment: You can just try to make it work in just one activity. How to transfer variables between activities is another issue. It's not suitable to explain here because it will need to touch more topics. You can find that in other posts such like these.
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=android+how+to+pass+variables+between+activities

Comment: Hi Fisher, i have resolved the issue in another approach. thanks for you help til now.

Comment: You can post your answer here for other people to reference.

Comment: i have added request signin code in LoginActivity.java and removed from MainActivity.java. so now sign-in and drive permission task is happening only once because of which that screen blink stop. in mainactivity.java code was everytime calling signin function and drive permission popup and that what was blinking on screen since user was having permission that popup comes and disappers. putting that code in loginactivity.java solved my issue.